# how to disable tooltip when button is disabled on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've a button like this

```
<asp:Button class="ico-back" title="Back" ID="btnAttritionBack" runat="server" disabled="disabled"></asp:Button>
```

when focus is on button it shows tooltip, otherwise doesn't show. But here on click event of this button in javascript i'm disabling it. Even after losing focus it doesn't hide tooltip.

```
$("input[id$='btnAttritionBack']").on("click", function (e) {
    LoadHRData("ALL");
    //$("#" + btnAttritionBack).removeAttr("title");
    $("#" + btnAttritionBack).prop("disabled", true);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I've tried disabling it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for the tooltip? When is the tooltip triggered? On hover?

Comment: @LShetty No i am not using any plugin. Yes tooltip is triggered upon hover.

Comment: How do you trigger on hover? is it bound to a class/ID? Post your code in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `ClientIDMode` to `Static` in the aspx markup.
By default, the ID rendered to the browser gets stuff put before it.

Comment: I can't set this property to static as there are so many other controls on this page using this

Comment: OK - you already have an `ico-back` class applied to it, so change your selector to be `$('.ico-back')` and within the function, use `$(this)` to reference the exact button clicked.

Comment: And you might need to use `CssClass` instead of `class` with it being webforms.